# Can we run drools 5 and drool 6 in parallel in same application ( drools- spring ) integration application

Tags: spring, drools-guvnor

I have existing application based on drools 5 rules engine and need to migrate to drools 6 but we can not do in one go i.e we have to do in multiple stages .
      So my requirement is i want to support droosl 5 and drool 6 execution in parallel in same application .

```
For that i  have created sample poc 
1) Created drools spring integration application having both drools 5 and drool 6 spring integration configuration files .

For Drools 5 : 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
      http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring-1.2.0.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <drools:grid-node id="node" />
      <drools:kbase id="drools5Kbase" node="node">
        <drools:resources >
            <!-- <drools:resource type="DRF" source="classpath:rules/distribution/regulatory/Test.rf" /> -->
            <drools:resource type="DRL" source="classpath:rules/Sample.drl" />
        </drools:resources>     
     </drools:kbase>    

</beans>


****Drools 6 :**** 

<kie:kmodule id="Drools6POC">

        <kie:kbase name="rules-two" packages="rules.two" />

        <kie:kbase name="drools6KieBase" packages="rules, process" includes="rules-two">
            <!--<kie:ksession name="ksessionRules">
                <kie:fileLogger file="drools.log" threaded="true" interval="10" />
                <kie:listeners>
                    <kie:ruleRuntimeEventListener ref="org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener" />
                    <kie:agendaEventListener ref="org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugAgendaEventListener" />
                    <kie:processEventListener ref="org.drools.core.event.DebugProcessEventListener" />
                </kie:listeners>
            </kie:ksession> 
            -->     
        </kie:kbase>

    </kie:kmodule>  


2) Added maven depencies for both drools 5 and drools 6 by changing drools 5 standard jar's group id and arctifact id in order to avoid version overwite 

3) With above  configuration drools 6 working fine but while loading drools 5 spring configuration file getting error 

INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70c44470: defining beans [node,drools5Kbase,drools5RuleSet]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 20, 2015 12:11:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@70c44470: defining beans [node,drools5Kbase,drools5RuleSet]; root of factory hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'drools5Kbase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVELDialectConfiguration:mvel:org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVELDialectConfiguration'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.sample.service.ProcessAndRuleService.main(ProcessAndRuleService.java:55)
Caused by: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVELDialectConfiguration:mvel:org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVELDialectConfiguration'
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:310)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:184)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:162)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:22)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:74)
    at org.drools.container.spring.beans.KnowledgeBaseBeanFactory.afterPropertiesSet(KnowledgeBaseBeanFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVELDialectConfiguration cannot be cast to org.drools.compiler.DialectConfiguration
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:305)
    ... 20 more


4) Pom.xml 

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestDroolsVersion</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestDroolsVersion</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>TestDroolsVersion</name>
  <description>TestDroolsVersion</description>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <drools6.version>6.1.0.Final</drools6.version>
         <spring.framework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
         <mvel2.version>2.1.0.drools4</mvel2.version>

      </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${drools6.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>


            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- START : Drools 5  -->

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools.custom</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core-custom</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version> 
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools.custom</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler-custom</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version> 
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.1.Final</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>


Your help will be appriciated .

1) Can we support drools 5 and drool 6 in parallel in same classpath 

2) If yes is there any way or any one have any sample 

Thanks and regards 
Sri
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run multiple versions of drools on the same container, but in this case both the versions are being installed in the same assembly.

Using maven it's possible to have a parent pom project and a multiple module sub-project structure. In this case there will not be any classpath collisions on the Drools compiler and this will work. Otherwise conflicting versions in the same project will need maven exclusions and i'm certain this will work correctly.